# Quadratic variation along a sequence vs quadratic variation of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am confused about how the following three facts are not in contradiction.

The question was essentially already raised [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92938/quadratic-variation-of-brownian-motion), but while I understand the proof in the link, I do not understand how the below is not a contradiction.

Let $B = (B_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ be a standard Brownian motion. Then

1. the quadratic variation of $B$ along the sequence $(\Pi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} := \left\{ \frac{k}{n}: 0 \leq k \leq n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of finite partitions of $[0,1]$ converges to $1$ in probability, i.e.

$$ V(\Pi_n) := \sum_{k = 0}^n \vert B(t_{i+1}) - B(t_{i}) \vert^2 \rightarrow 1, ~~~ \text{in probability} $$

2. the $2$-variation of $B$ goes to $+ \infty$ almost surely, i.e.

$$ \Vert B_{\omega}(\cdot) \Vert_{2-var}^2  := \sup_{P ~~ \text{fin. partition}} \sum_{t_i \in P} \vert B(t_i) - B(t_{i+1}) \vert^2 = + \infty, ~~~ \mathbb{P}-a.e. \omega \in \Omega $$

(here the $\sup$ goes over all finite partitions of $[0,1]$).

3. for a continuous function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the $2$-variation is equal to the limit of the quadratic variation along any sequence of finite partitions whose mesh size goes to $0$, i.e. for any sequence of partitions $\{P_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with

$$ \max_{t_i \in P_n} \vert t_{i+1} - t_i \vert \rightarrow 0, ~~~ n \rightarrow \infty $$

we have

$$ \sup_{P ~~ \text{fin. partition}} \sum_{t_i \in P} \vert f(t_{i+1}) - f(t_{i}) \vert^2 =  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{t_i \in P_n} \vert f(t_{i+1}) - f(t_{i}) \vert^2 $$

Thus there should be a contradiction since 1. implies that there exists a subsequence $(P_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ s.t.

$$ \max_{t_i \in P_{n_k}} \vert t_{i+1} - t_i \vert \rightarrow 0, ~~~ k \rightarrow \infty $$

and $V(P_{n_k}) \rightarrow 1$ almost surely. But then, since Brownian motion has sample paths almost surely, 3) implies that the limit of $V(P_{n_k})$ coincides with the quadratic variation i.e. with the $\sup$, which is infinite almost surely.

Comment: Point 2 is not correct. Brownian motion has finite quadratic varation but infinite variation.

Comment: Are you sure about this? The question I linked and the paper linked in its first answer say otherwise. (I agree with infinite total variation of course though)

Comment: Another proof of 2) is given in Chapter 13.9 of “Multidimensional Stochastic Processes as Rough Paths Theory and Applications”, written by Peter K. Friz and Nicolas B. Victoir, ISBN 9780521876070.

Comment: Point 3. is incorrect. It should be "the quadratic variation is equal to the limit..." Not "the 2-variation is equal to the limit..."

Comment: So then the proof given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700991/definition-of-total-variation/4323104#4323104) has a mistake somewhere? Do you have an explicit counter-example to the 3)?

Comment: The question and answer you linked to mention neither quadratic variation nor 2-variation

Comment: @Bananach the question and answer ought to go through with exactly the same argument for $p$-variation instead of $1$-variation

Comment: No. $|x-y|^p\leq |x-z|^p+|z-y|^p$ holds for $p=1$ but not for $p=2$.

Comment: @Bananach You're right - there needs to be a correction factor of $2^{p-1}$ on the right-hand side. And I cannot really repair the proof either.

Comment: You might find this post intersting : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92938/quadratic-variation-of-brownian-motion